# AWS Golang sdk - change policy to sns topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I'm trying to subscribe an endpoint to a S3 bucket's events through an SNS topic.

What I **achieved** to have through the golang sdk:

- Create an SNS topic
- Make the S3 bucket's events publish to the SNS topic
- Subscribe my endpoint the the SNS topic.

At this point, everything is supposed to work, but...the ***S3 bucket does not have the permission to publish to the SNS topic***.
The default SNS policy allows only the owner to publish to the topic.

I can fix this manually from the console changing the topic's policy to allow the S3 bucket ARN to publish to the topic (see image below), but ***the goal is change the policy through the Golang sdk***.

Policy in AWS console

[image: Policy in AWS console]

As you can notice from the image above, I don't want to grant access to a specific AWS user, but to a specific S3 bucket (through its ARN).
I couldn't find anything in the SNS sdk documentation (`AddPermission` only allows to specify AWS account ids).

Any idea?

Comment: Please paste the golang you have already tried that hasn't worked.